# android date format like in gmail

Tags: java, android, date, formatting

How to format Date object in Android similar like Gmail displays it
1. If the date is <24h from now, print hour ie 12:12am
2. If the date >24h but <1 week, print day name, ie Wednesday
3. If the date > 1 week, print date ie 2013-08-12

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621383/format-dates-like-google-gmail has the same question with the answer, but for Javascrit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good place to get started:

`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, long now, long minResolution)`

*Parameters*
*time* is the time to describe, in milliseconds.
*now* is the current time in milliseconds.
*minResolution* is the minimum timespan to report.

For example, a time 3 seconds in the past will be reported as "0 minutes ago" if this is set to `MINUTE_IN_MILLIS`. Pass one of 0, `MINUTE_IN_MILLIS`, `HOUR_IN_MILLIS`, `DAY_IN_MILLIS`, `WEEK_IN_MILLIS`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)